# How to get Whether the subscription made through In App Purchase is Active or InActive?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have implemented IAP , I am storing the transaction state in UserDefault, Depending on value in UserDefault I will decide whether to show Buy Button or not in ViewWillAppear,But the problem is when we uninstall app Userdefault values gets cleared and I will not be getting right values to handle visibility of Buy Button, Is there any other way with which I will be able to handle or check whether the user has purchased the product previously? if he has purchased the product I will not show any Buy button in UI if he hasn't purchased I will show Buy button.

```
// Calling this in ViewWillAppear
if isSubscriptionActive() {
            subscriptionStatusLbl.text = "Active Plan"
            shouldhidePriceView(isHidden: true)
        } else {
            subscriptionStatusLbl.text = "Subscription Plan"
            shouldhidePriceView(isHidden: false)
        }

// This function return Bool value depending on whether the value is present in UserDefault or not

 func isSubscriptionActive() -> Bool {
        let purchaseStatus` = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productID)
        if purchaseStatus {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }


    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased :
                print("Successful Transaction")
// here I am storing value in Userdefault
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: productID)
                shouldhidePriceView(isHidden: true)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break ;
            case .failed:
                print("Failed Transaction")
                if let error = transaction.error {
                    print("Transaction failed due to : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                shouldhidePriceView(isHidden: false)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break ;
            case .restored:
                print("Restored : Already Purchased");
                customNavBarView.blueToothBtn.isHidden = true
                shouldhidePriceView(isHidden: true)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: productID)
                break;
            default:
                break;
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't have any backend (or any user account) and everything is stored locally in your app.

If I'm correct, the only way is to add a "Restore" link on your paywall and a "Restore" button in your settings page. Here is the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/restoring_purchased_products).

Comment: Is there any Api just like android getAvailablePurchase() with which I get all details about product such as whether product is active or not etc  @romainsalles

Comment: I don't think so, no. And don't call the "restore" method without the user asking for it, since it could display an "login popup" and your user wouldn't understand why.